# EntityFramework - Detect DatabaseGenerated properties

Tags: c#

I'm using EntityFramework - Code First, DBContext with POCO classes.

At runtime, how can i detect properties belongs to fields that generated in the database, marked as .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption , .IsRowVersion (readonly?) etc.

I looked at `var xxx = Entity.GetType().GetProperty("ID").Get`... , no luck.

```
public partial class OnMuhasebeContext : DbContext
{   

    public bool IsDatabaseGeneratedProperty <?>(...)
    {
        // Parameters : 
        // We know all poco classes of course
        // also parameters can be instance type
    }
}
```

Update: 
please read "database generated" as "field whose value generated by database" and marked in the model to reflect that.
These properties are both belongs to database generated fields and marked as identity and RowVersion using Fluent API.

```
public class POCOMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<POCO>
{
    public POCOMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        this.Property(t => t.RowVersion)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();
     }
 }
```

Important point: How to get properties are marked in the model or code first model, using Fluent API or Data Annotions. Databases itself not important, like the philosophy behind the Entity Framework.

Comment: Uhm, you say you are using Code First. How could you have database generated properties? Or do you mean you have fields that are required by the database?

Comment: Please look at update section. RowVersion-Timestamp field's value setted by database at updates. Autoincrement Identity field values are given by database at inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I get what you are trying to achieve.

Sadly, you cannot access the `EntityTypeConfiguration` out of the box.
However, there is something else you can do. You could use your own `Attribute` and place it on properties that have database generated values.

An example:

Our custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class GeneratedByDatabaseAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

A very simple poco that uses the attribute:

```
public class SimplePoco
{
    [GeneratedByDatabase]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [GeneratedByDatabase]
    public int RowVersion { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is where the magic happens. I'm using `GetPropertyInfo` to get the member from a lambda expression. This method is by far incomplete but there are enough samples all arround stackoverflow.
In short: I get the `PropertyInfo` for the given property and check if it has our custom `GeneratedByDatabaseAttribute` attribute.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public bool IsDatabaseGeneratedProperty<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var property = GetPropertyInfo(propertyExpression);
        var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute<GeneratedByDatabaseAttribute>();
        return attribute != null;
    }

    public PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> propertyLambda)
    {
        var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member == null)
        {
            var ubody = (UnaryExpression)propertyLambda.Body;
            member = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        return member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
}
```

This is how I tested it with LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var context = new MyContext();
    var result = context.IsDatabaseGeneratedProperty<SimplePoco>(poco => poco.Id);
    // result: True
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    result = context.IsDatabaseGeneratedProperty<SimplePoco>(poco => poco.Name);
    // result: False
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely well working code. Thank you very much. And you give wonderfull explanation, i quickly run sample project, thank you very much. (system doesn't allow me to vote for now, but i will do it)

Comment: FluentApi based mappings already exist in entityframework model, and if possible i want to use it. Can i use this method to get information from entityframework model or class? I'm looking entityframework source code to understand it.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Using my solution is still a generic solution which you would be able to apply across the whole application. Sidenote: You should be able to accept the answer. Entity Frameworks is freely available on its codeplex site.

Comment: Jordy Langen, Thank you very much.